# using QuerySet to fetch data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a rest api which gives the weather data for a particular city and n days. I've created a model which specifies all the required fields. I've populated the database using management commands.

I've tried using Q method to query the database. but I am making error somewhere and I am unable to identify it.

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render


from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import weatherdata
from .serializers import weatherdataserializer
from django.http import Http404

from django.db.models import Q


# Create your views here.


class weatherList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        weather = weatherdata.objects.all()
        serializer = weatherdataserializer(weather,  many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = weatherdataserializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class weatherDetail(APIView):
    def get_queryset(self,*args , **kwargs):
        queryset_list = weatherdata.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(city_name__icontains = query) |
                Q(city_id__icontains = query)
            ).distinct()
        return queryset_list
```

```
#serialisers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import weatherdata

class weatherdataserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model  = weatherdata
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = (
            'city_name',
            'city_id',
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
            'dt_txt',
            'temp',
            'temp_min',
            'temp_max',
            'pressure',
            'sea_level',
            'grnd_level',
            'humidity',
            'main',
            'description',
            'clouds',
            'wind_speed',
            'wind_degree',
        )
```

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from django.db import models

class weatherdata(models.Model):
    city_name   = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    city_id     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    latitude    = models.FloatField(null=True , blank=True)
    longitude   = models.FloatField(null=True , blank=True)
    dt_txt      = models.DateTimeField()
    temp        = models.FloatField(null = False)
    temp_min    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    temp_max    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    pressure    = models.FloatField(null = False) 
    sea_level   = models.FloatField(null = False)
    grnd_level  = models.FloatField(null = False)
    humidity    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    main        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    clouds      = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    wind_speed  = models.FloatField(null = False)
    wind_degree = models.FloatField(null = False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name
```

```
#urls.py


from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

# Serializers define the API representation.
from importweather import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^weatherdata', views.weatherList.as_view()),
    url(r'^weatherdata/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', views.weatherDetail.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/weatherdata/Chennai/5
should fetch only the weather in Chennai for the past 5 days(note.the DateTime field is as follows: "2019-08-12T12:00:00Z" , i.e Date-Time)

Comment: You don't seem to have said what is going wrong.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the API is showing all the values stored in by database. It is not showing only the required cities. I don't know how to make the QuerySet work correctly

Comment: But your URLs don't match what you claim you are doing. You say you are going to "/weatherdata/Chennai/5", but your URL only accepts "/weatherdata/5". And again your view is filtering on a "q" value; where is that provided? You need to explain your problem consistently.

Answer (score 1):

How does this URL **http://127.0.0.1:8000/weatherdata/Chennai/5** map to your `weatherDetail` view? There's no GET request parameter `q` in it.

Your detail view only filters based on the `q` parameter, so your above URL cannot return filtered results.

With your URL pattern, `pk` needs to be digits, so it doesn't match but it matches the `weatherdata` general list view because you don't specify a `$` to terminate it.

Change your URL pattern to:

```
url(r'^weatherdata/(?P<city>.+)/(?P<days>[0-9]+)', views.weatherDetail.as_view()
```

and then in your view you can use `kwargs['city']` and `kwargs['days']` to retrieve the URL parameters.

Note also that `APIView` does not have a `get_queryset()` method, so your method won't be called. You need to make it also a `ListAPIView`.

Comment: I could modify the 5 later on, my first task is to show the particular city given. what I mean is, once the city is classified, I could use the same logic to sort the number of date also

Comment: how should I modify url in url patterns? should it be url(r'^weatherdata/city/', views.weatherDetail.as_view())

Comment: I’ve written it in my answer

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) to understand how these url patterns work. I've linked to the 1.11 docs as you're apparently not using Django 2.x

Answer (score 0):

In your serializer `Meta class` fields should be in list but you put them on an array. I think this may solve your problem.